# MySQL Maximum value

Tags: mysql, max

have a couple of dates in a few fields, basically

```
SELECT MAX(MAX(DATE_A),MAX(DATE_B)) from table
```

DATE_A and DATE_B are dates, i basically want the maximum of the latest date of either date A or date B

I searched online but max as a keyword makes it very hard to find what im looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(GREATEST(date_a,date_b)) FROM table
```

This first uses `GREATEST(date_a,date_b)` to reduce these two columns into just one, containing the greatest value for each row.

The `MAX` then selects the one maximum value over all of these.

It also prevents repeated evaluation of `MAX` to make things a littler more efficient.

[`GREATEST` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), [`MAX` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max).

Note that `GREATEST` operates across columns, whereas `MAX` operates across rows, which is why you need to use them both to get the single maximum value across both rows and columns.

Comment: Yup this is what seems to work! and greatest also takes more values than date_a and b (there are 7 sometimes 8 dates)

Answer (score 2):

```
select greatest(date_a,date_b) as recent from table
```

Comment: Max(greatest(date_a,date_b)) seems to work well (greatest results in many records)

Comment: `SELECT MAX(GREATEST(date_a,date_b)) from table` is probably closer to what the OP had in mind but the GREATEST function is what he needs. +1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT IF(MAX(DATE_A)>MAX(DATE_B),MAX(DATE_A), MAX(DATE_B)) FROM table
```